# Remove the blank or margin around the figure with 'pgfplots' in LaTeX

Tags: pgfplots, margins

When drawing with `pgfplots`, there are blank around the figures which make those can't be centered rightly. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.arrows,datavisualization,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
    &
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[xticklabel style={text width=1em},yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision =2,/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},scaled ticks=false,width=7.4cm,height=4cm,xmin=0,xmax=12,ylabel={the first}]
          \addplot[
          scatter,only marks, point meta=explicit symbolic,
          scatter/classes={
            a={mark=o,draw=black},
            b={mark=square*},
            c={mark=triangle*}
            },
            ] table [meta=label]{
                x   y   label
1   0.55476356  c
2   0.363722187 c
3   0.81286394  c
4   0.875783813 c
5   0.315270863 c
6   0.827911581 c
7   0.720070049 c
8   0.347479399 c
9   0.27043531  c
10  0.490422201 c
11  0.69325892  c
1   0.735883237 a
2   0.129003395 a
3   0.461826926 a
4   0.756650854 a
5   0.305755095 a
6   0.263120301 a
7   0.38954705  a
8   0.07894936  a
9   0.984081129 a
10  0.712322139 a
11  0.146583606 a
1   0.186438911 b
2   0.483752955 b
3   0.955453588 b
4   0.931741157 b
5   0.307806207 b
6   0.932585214 b
7   0.390174549 b
8   0.397465905 b
9   0.893646115 b
10  0.177956892 b
11  0.250648427 b
            };
          \addplot[mark=none, black,dashed,domain=0:12,samples=2] {0.336};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}\\
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[xticklabel style={text width=1em},yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision =2,/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},scaled ticks=false,width=7.4cm,height=4cm,xmin=0,xmax=12,ylabel={the second} ]
          \addplot[
          scatter,only marks, point meta=explicit symbolic,
          scatter/classes={
            a={mark=o,draw=black},
            b={mark=square*},
            c={mark=triangle*}
            },
            ] table [meta=label]{
                x   y   label
1   0.55476356  c
2   0.363722187 c
3   0.81286394  c
4   0.875783813 c
5   0.315270863 c
6   0.827911581 c
7   0.720070049 c
8   0.347479399 c
9   0.27043531  c
10  0.490422201 c
11  0.69325892  c
1   0.735883237 a
2   0.129003395 a
3   0.461826926 a
4   0.756650854 a
5   0.305755095 a
6   0.263120301 a
7   0.38954705  a
8   0.07894936  a
9   0.984081129 a
10  0.712322139 a
11  0.146583606 a
1   0.186438911 b
2   0.483752955 b
3   0.955453588 b
4   0.931741157 b
5   0.307806207 b
6   0.932585214 b
7   0.390174549 b
8   0.397465905 b
9   0.893646115 b
10  0.177956892 b
11  0.250648427 b

            };
            \addplot[mark=none, black,dashed,domain=0:12,samples=2] {0.778};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}&
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[xticklabel style={text width=1em},yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision =2,/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},scaled ticks=false,width=7.4cm,height=4cm,xmin=0,xmax=12,ylabel={the third} ]
          \addplot[
          scatter,only marks, point meta=explicit symbolic,
          scatter/classes={
            a={mark=o,draw=black},
            b={mark=square*},
            c={mark=triangle*}
            },
            ] table [meta=label]{
                x   y   label
1   0.55476356  c
2   0.363722187 c
3   0.81286394  c
4   0.875783813 c
5   0.315270863 c
6   0.827911581 c
7   0.720070049 c
8   0.347479399 c
9   0.27043531  c
10  0.490422201 c
11  0.69325892  c
1   0.735883237 a
2   0.129003395 a
3   0.461826926 a
4   0.756650854 a
5   0.305755095 a
6   0.263120301 a
7   0.38954705  a
8   0.07894936  a
9   0.984081129 a
10  0.712322139 a
11  0.146583606 a
1   0.186438911 b
2   0.483752955 b
3   0.955453588 b
4   0.931741157 b
5   0.307806207 b
6   0.932585214 b
7   0.390174549 b
8   0.397465905 b
9   0.893646115 b
10  0.177956892 b
11  0.250648427 b

            };
            \addplot[mark=none, black,dashed,domain=0:12,samples=2] {0.778};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Outputs:

[image]

How to remove the left blank marked by red line to move the figure as a whole to the center of the page? The figures on the left needs to be aligned left with the vertical line on the left, and the figures on the right needs to be aligned right with the vertical line on the right.

Comment: Remove the `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `tabular` environment. If you wish, you could get fancy here with boxes or subfigures, but a simple `\hfill` does the job you want on the first line.

The reason you get the extra space is the padding `tabular` puts between and before/after columns.

[image: align top row to right with \hfill and leave bottom row be without tabular]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.arrows,datavisualization,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \hfill
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xticklabel style={text width=1em},yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision =2,/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},scaled ticks=false,width=7.4cm,height=4cm,xmin=0,xmax=12,ylabel={the first}]
      \addplot[
      scatter,only marks, point meta=explicit symbolic,
      scatter/classes={
        a={mark=o,draw=black},
        b={mark=square*},
        c={mark=triangle*}
      },
      ] table [meta=label]{
        x   y   label
        1   0.55476356  c
        2   0.363722187 c
        3   0.81286394  c
        4   0.875783813 c
        5   0.315270863 c
        6   0.827911581 c
        7   0.720070049 c
        8   0.347479399 c
        9   0.27043531  c
        10  0.490422201 c
        11  0.69325892  c
        1   0.735883237 a
        2   0.129003395 a
        3   0.461826926 a
        4   0.756650854 a
        5   0.305755095 a
        6   0.263120301 a
        7   0.38954705  a
        8   0.07894936  a
        9   0.984081129 a
        10  0.712322139 a
        11  0.146583606 a
        1   0.186438911 b
        2   0.483752955 b
        3   0.955453588 b
        4   0.931741157 b
        5   0.307806207 b
        6   0.932585214 b
        7   0.390174549 b
        8   0.397465905 b
        9   0.893646115 b
        10  0.177956892 b
        11  0.250648427 b
      };
      \addplot[mark=none, black,dashed,domain=0:12,samples=2] {0.336};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xticklabel style={text width=1em},yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision =2,/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},scaled ticks=false,width=7.4cm,height=4cm,xmin=0,xmax=12,ylabel={the second} ]
      \addplot[
      scatter,only marks, point meta=explicit symbolic,
      scatter/classes={
        a={mark=o,draw=black},
        b={mark=square*},
        c={mark=triangle*}
      },
      ] table [meta=label]{
        x   y   label
        1   0.55476356  c
        2   0.363722187 c
        3   0.81286394  c
        4   0.875783813 c
        5   0.315270863 c
        6   0.827911581 c
        7   0.720070049 c
        8   0.347479399 c
        9   0.27043531  c
        10  0.490422201 c
        11  0.69325892  c
        1   0.735883237 a
        2   0.129003395 a
        3   0.461826926 a
        4   0.756650854 a
        5   0.305755095 a
        6   0.263120301 a
        7   0.38954705  a
        8   0.07894936  a
        9   0.984081129 a
        10  0.712322139 a
        11  0.146583606 a
        1   0.186438911 b
        2   0.483752955 b
        3   0.955453588 b
        4   0.931741157 b
        5   0.307806207 b
        6   0.932585214 b
        7   0.390174549 b
        8   0.397465905 b
        9   0.893646115 b
        10  0.177956892 b
        11  0.250648427 b
        
      };
      \addplot[mark=none, black,dashed,domain=0:12,samples=2] {0.778};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}\hfill
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xticklabel style={text width=1em},yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision =2,/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},scaled ticks=false,width=7.4cm,height=4cm,xmin=0,xmax=12,ylabel={the third} ]
      \addplot[
      scatter,only marks, point meta=explicit symbolic,
      scatter/classes={
        a={mark=o,draw=black},
        b={mark=square*},
        c={mark=triangle*}
      },
      ] table [meta=label]{
        x   y   label
        1   0.55476356  c
        2   0.363722187 c
        3   0.81286394  c
        4   0.875783813 c
        5   0.315270863 c
        6   0.827911581 c
        7   0.720070049 c
        8   0.347479399 c
        9   0.27043531  c
        10  0.490422201 c
        11  0.69325892  c
        1   0.735883237 a
        2   0.129003395 a
        3   0.461826926 a
        4   0.756650854 a
        5   0.305755095 a
        6   0.263120301 a
        7   0.38954705  a
        8   0.07894936  a
        9   0.984081129 a
        10  0.712322139 a
        11  0.146583606 a
        1   0.186438911 b
        2   0.483752955 b
        3   0.955453588 b
        4   0.931741157 b
        5   0.307806207 b
        6   0.932585214 b
        7   0.390174549 b
        8   0.397465905 b
        9   0.893646115 b
        10  0.177956892 b
        11  0.250648427 b
        
      };
      \addplot[mark=none, black,dashed,domain=0:12,samples=2] {0.778};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you want subcaptions or fancier alignment, look at `subcaption`.

Comment: Why don't you add `\hfill` between the second and the third figures?

Comment: @Y.zeng There didn't seem any need. You can if you prefer to and I might well do it when I saw this in the context of the page (though probably it will not get onto a text page given its size).

Comment: If there isn't `\hfill`, the right figure may not align to the right line of the right side. Am I right?

Comment: @Y.zeng That's possible. In that case, the distance from the left margin to the left of the figure would equal the distance from the right margin to the right of the figure. But if you want to ensure alignment with the margins, you should definitely use `\hfill`, indeed.

Comment: Why do you confirm this: **the distance from the left margin to the left of the figure would equal the distance from the right margin to the right of the figure**?

Comment: @Y.zeng Because you have `\centering` at the start of the `figure` environment. If you don't put `\hfill`, LaTeX will simply centre what's on the line i.e. it will equalise those distances. That's why I wouldn't automatically use `\hfill` here. I'm not usually hung up about alignment with the margins ;).Given the image on the previous line, though, I probably should put `\hfill` for safety's sake. The output looked right, so I didn't think about it.

Comment: I have tested the `\centering`. It will center them but not equalise them. May you check it now.

Comment: @Y.zeng It does equalise them, but there is internal space, too e.g. the space inside the node of an axis label may differ from that inside the node containing a number on an axis or whatever. You can experiment by putting `\fbox` around things (may need to adjust the inner spacing) to see what is inside and outside the box. I get the same output with and without `\hfill`.